# How to display a VSCode Hover when mousing over a Decorations before icon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode Extension https://github.com/dev-tools-ai/devtoolsai-vscode-plugin

And referencing the image below, wondering...

- Is it possible to show a Hover when mousing over not just the
  decoration, but additionally the icon shown in **1** of the image.
  Currently this was put in place with [before: { contentIconPath:
  "image.svg" }](https://github.com/dev-tools-ai/devtoolsai-vscode-plugin/blob/master/src/providerDecorations.ts#L204)
- Additional question.  Is it possible to control the ordering of entries within a Hover.
  I'd like to move what I inserted shown in **2** to **3**

[image]